# Google Analytics how to make entrance and unique page view match?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a site which has a homepage which is example.com
On this page I have a purchase button which if the user clicks on it will go to another domain to make the purchase (which I cannot track with cross-domain tracking). After he makes the purchase he will redirect again to my site at the page example.com/thankyou
In analytics, I would expect that the entrance and unique page view at the thankyou page is the same. Meanwhile in my site is see 2000 unique visits at the thank you page and less than half entrance. Why is that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, you need to completely understand the difference between those metrics: [entrance vs sessions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2956047?hl=en).

Providing an answer to your question requires more knowledge about the site: is the thank-you page open? is indexed in searchers? does it have internal links?

Despite you are not able to setup a cross-domain tracking, when the user returns they still have the Analytics cookie (you will lost medium/source but other values are there)

Comment: Thanks @emirodgar however, the page is not indexed and yes it has internal links so that thank you page is also an upsell page where the user can purchase something else and go to the next page. However it is still strange that i have such a difference, as far as the user can enter that page only from the payment providers i should see unique views matching entrance or maybe a small difference but not such a huge difference.

Comment: How long is your Google Analytics session? How long takes the payment? is the thank-you page opened in a new tab after payment?

Google Analytics records an entrance for each page that a user begins a new session on. So the number of entrances given for a specific page shows how many users began their session with that page.

Comment: Average session is around 3-4 minutes so looks good. The payment takes 3-5 seconds and doesn't open a new tab but re-directs directly from the payment page. What i notice is that from the homepage when you click on add to cart in that case a new tab is opened which is the payment provider, and from that tab the user after he makes payment he land on the thank you page (leaving the homepage tab opened, but dont know if this is an issue or not)